# É uma boa ideia utilizar interfaces para especificar quais métodos mágicos uma classe implementará?

Tags: php, interface, métodos-mágicos

Eu já vi alguns códigos em PHP que, para verificar se uma classe possui o método `__toString`, é utilizada a função `method_exists`.

Exemplo:

```
if (method_exists($object, '__toString')) echo $object;
```

Por outro lado, já vi interfaces que utilizam o método `__toString` para obrigar as classes que o implementam a ter esse método.

```
interface StringableInterface
{
     public function __toString();
}

if ($object instanceof StringableInterface) echo $object;
```

Quais são as vantagens de se utilizar uma `interface` que contenha `__toString`, ao invés de utilizar apenas a verificação que esse método exista na classe?

Answer (score 2):

Embora ambos em muitos casos possam parecer servir "quase" para o mesmo efeito na verdade o `instanceof` procura informar se uma determinada classe implementa uma determinada interface, o que, não é o mesmo que saber se o método existe ou não.

Podemos colocar depois uma análise mais cuidada quanto à performance e em resultado podemos obter resultados interessantes, analise o código que encontrei e que na minha opinião ajuda a perceber...

```
interface HasMethod {
    public function myMethod();
}

class MyClass1 implements HasMethod {
    public function myMethod() {}
}

class MyClass2 {
    public function myMethod() {}
}

$myClass1 = new MyClass1();
$myClass2 = new MyClass2();

$times = [0,0,0];
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    $start = microtime(1);
    ($myClass1 instanceof HasMethod) && $j++;
    $times[0] += microtime(1) - $start;

    $start = microtime(1);
    (method_exists($myClass1, 'myMethod')) && $j++;
    $times[1] += microtime(1) - $start;

    $start = microtime(1);
    (method_exists($myClass2, 'myMethod')) && $j++;
    $times[2] += microtime(1) - $start;
}

print_r($times);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.46121835708618 //instanceOf
    [1] => 0.53055930137634 //method_exists com interface
    [2] => 0.4961085319519  //method_exists sem interface
)
```

Utilizar o `instanceof` é ligeiramente mais rápido do que `method_exists()`.

A vantagem da velocidade é particularmente visível quando utilizo uma interface ou o método não existe.

Eu pessoalmente gosto mais de utilizar contratos como o interface pelo que prefiro o `instanceof` como "solução elegante".

Para terminar uma questão que na minha opinião é muito importante e que por vezes falha a muitos de nós...

É verdade que `method_exists()` retorna o valor de `TRUE` se o método existir. No entanto também o faz para métodos privados o que pode ser problemático. Para isso existe também o `is_callable()` que no exemplo que indiquei irá retornar `FALSE`. Sei que foge um pouco ao escopo da pergunta mas achei importante referir!

Comment: Esclarecedor, principalmente a questão do `method_exists` detectar o `private`. Tinha  me esquecido desse detalhe. Faz toda a diferença sim